# How to unhide a div based on two Boolean function outputs

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to use an input box to check if the input begins with a letter A-M, and secondly if the number of characters is odd or even, then unhide a div if these conditions are met. I am getting one error:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null
at org.html:89
Code below.
Thanks.
I am trying to change the display style with my if statement at the end of the functions.
However, because of the null type error nothing happens.
If I can get the first one to work, I intend to duplicate the method for the other tables.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>ITP-03</title>
        <meta name="description" content="A calculator">
        <style>
        .title{
        border: 10px;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        text-align:center;
        width: 210px;
        color:black;
        border: solid black 1px;
        font-family: sans-serif;
        }
        input[type="button"]
        {
        border: 10px;
        background-color:#46eb34;
        color: black;
        border-color:#46eb34 ;
        width:100%;
        }
        input[type="text"]
        {
        border: 10px;
        text-align: right;
        background-color:white;
        border-color: black ;
        width:100%
        }
        input[type="username"]
        {
        border: 10px;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        text-align: left;
        color: black;
        border: solid #46eb34 1px;
        background-color:white;
        border-color: black ;
        width:20%
        }
        </style>
        <script>
        //function for displaying values
        function dis(val)
        {
        document.getElementById("calc").value+=val;
         }
        //function for evaluation
        function solve()
        {
        let x = document.getElementById("calc").value;
        let y = eval(x);
        document.getElementById("calc").value = y;
        }
        //function for clearing the display
        function clr()
        {
        document.getElementById("calc").value = "";
        }
        function isEven() 
        {
        var value = document.getElementById("username").value.length;
        if (value%2 == 0) {
            document.getElementById("check2").innerHTML = "even";
            return true;
        }
        if (value%2 !=0) {
            document.getElementById("check2").innerHTML = "odd";
            return false;
        }
        }
        function beforeN(value) {
        var firstletter = document.getElementById("username").value.substring(0,1);
        var str = "abcdefghijklm.";
        if (str.includes(firstletter)){
            document.getElementById("check1").innerHTML = "a-m";
            return true;

        }
        else {
            document.getElementById("check1").innerHTML = "n-z";
            return false;
        }
        }
        if(beforeN(document.getElementById("username").value) && (isEven(document.getElementById("username").value))){
           document.getElementById("amodd").style.display= "block";
        }
        </script>
    </head>




<body>
<p id="check1">a</p>
<p id="check2">a</p>
<p class = title>Enter your iu username</p>
<input type="username" id="username" name="iu username"/>
<br>
<button onclick=beforeN(document.getElementById("username").value) type ="button">Submit</button>

<div id ="amodd" style=display:none>
<div class = title >ITP-03 Calculator A-M ODD</div>
<table border="1">
<tr>
<td><input type="button" value="c" onclick="clr()"/> </td>
<td colspan="3"><input type="text" id="calc"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="button" value="+" onclick="dis('+')"/> </td>
<td><input type="button" value="1" onclick="dis('1')"/> </td>
<td><input type="button" value="3" onclick="dis('3')"/> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="button" value="/" onclick="dis('/)"/> </td>
<td><input type="button" value="5" onclick="dis('5')"/> </td>
<td><input type="button" value="7" onclick="dis('7')"/> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="button" value="." onclick="dis('.')"/> </td>

<td><input type="button" value="9" onclick="dis('9')"/> </td>
<td><input type="button" value="=" onclick="solve()"/> </td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>      
</body>
```

Comment: Could you share the full HTML and JS

Comment: Yes, Just updated

Comment: I don't see any change to the code.

Comment: Sorry, how about now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few things to note here.

You are missing the quotes for the onclick attribute value. Others have already pointed that out.

The error that you were seeing is because your if condition resides outside a function. So, it will be executed on page load in the order in which you have written it. If you have it before the body, it will be executed before the DOM loads. In such cases, you should put it within the body at the end.

Also, the if condition will only be executed when your page loads. Since your button has an onclick attribute, it will execute only that function that you invoke. That will not help you update the page(hide and unhide divs) every time the button is clicked. I would suggest you put the if-condition within a function and invoke the function on the button click.

Also note that I have changed your if condition to remove all the parameters you were passing, since you were not using it. You were fetching the values again in your function.

Also, since you want both `beforeN` and `isEven` functions to be executed every time the button is clicked, I have changed it to execute the functions and store the result in a variable. Otherwise, it will only execute the `isEven` method if `beforeN` evaluates to true. Also included an else condition to hide the div when the conditions are not met.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>ITP-03</title>
    <meta name="description" content="A calculator">
    <style>
        .title {
            border: 10px;
            margin-bottom: 10px;
            text-align: center;
            width: 210px;
            color: black;
            border: solid black 1px;
            font-family: sans-serif;
        }

        input[type="button"] {
            border: 10px;
            background-color: #46eb34;
            color: black;
            border-color: #46eb34;
            width: 100%;
        }

        input[type="text"] {
            border: 10px;
            text-align: right;
            background-color: white;
            border-color: black;
            width: 100%
        }

        input[type="username"] {
            border: 10px;
            margin-bottom: 10px;
            text-align: left;
            color: black;
            border: solid #46eb34 1px;
            background-color: white;
            border-color: black;
            width: 20%
        }
    </style>

</head>




<body>
    <p id="check1">a</p>
    <p id="check2">a</p>
    <p class=title>Enter your iu username</p>
    <input type="username" id="username" name="iu username" />
    <br>
    <button onclick="exFun()" type="button">Submit</button>

    <div id="amodd" style=display:none>
        <div class=title>ITP-03 Calculator A-M ODD</div>
        <table border="1">
            <tr>
                <td><input type="button" value="c" onclick="clr()" /> </td>
                <td colspan="3"><input type="text" id="calc" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="button" value="+" onclick="dis('+')" /> </td>
                <td><input type="button" value="1" onclick="dis('1')" /> </td>
                <td><input type="button" value="3" onclick="dis('3')" /> </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="button" value="/" onclick="dis('/)" /> </td>
                <td><input type="button" value="5" onclick="dis('5')" /> </td>
                <td><input type="button" value="7" onclick="dis('7')" /> </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="button" value="." onclick="dis('.')" /> </td>

                <td><input type="button" value="9" onclick="dis('9')" /> </td>
                <td><input type="button" value="=" onclick="solve()" /> </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>

    <script>
        //function for displaying values
        function dis(val) {
            document.getElementById("calc").value += val;
        }
        //function for evaluation
        function solve() {
            let x = document.getElementById("calc").value;
            let y = eval(x);
            document.getElementById("calc").value = y;
        }
        //function for clearing the display
        function clr() {
            document.getElementById("calc").value = "";
        }
        function isEven() {
            var value = document.getElementById("username").value.length;
            if (value % 2 == 0) {
                document.getElementById("check2").innerHTML = "even";
                return true;
            }
            if (value % 2 != 0) {
                document.getElementById("check2").innerHTML = "odd";
                return false;
            }
        }
        function beforeN(value) {
            var firstletter = document.getElementById("username").value.substring(0, 1);
            var str = "abcdefghijklm.";
            if (str.includes(firstletter)) {
                document.getElementById("check1").innerHTML = "a-m";
                return true;

            }
            else {
                document.getElementById("check1").innerHTML = "n-z";
                return false;
            }
        }

        function exFun() {
            var beforeNResult = beforeN();
            var isEvenResult = isEven();
            if (beforeNResult && isEvenResult) {
                document.getElementById("amodd").style.display = "block";
            }else{
                document.getElementById("amodd").style.display = "none";
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

you should put script after element.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>ITP-03</title>
        <meta name="description" content="A calculator">
        <style>
        .title{
        border: 10px;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        text-align:center;
        width: 210px;
        color:black;
        border: solid black 1px;
        font-family: sans-serif;
        }
        input[type="button"]
        {
        border: 10px;
        background-color:#46eb34;
        color: black;
        border-color:#46eb34 ;
        width:100%;
        }
        input[type="text"]
        {
        border: 10px;
        text-align: right;
        background-color:white;
        border-color: black ;
        width:100%
        }
        input[type="username"]
        {
        border: 10px;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        text-align: left;
        color: black;
        border: solid #46eb34 1px;
        background-color:white;
        border-color: black ;
        width:20%
        }
        </style>

    </head>




    <body>
    <p id="check1">a</p>
    <p id="check2">a</p>
    <p class = title>Enter your iu username</p>
    <input type="username" id="username" name="iu username"/>
    <br>
    <button onclick='beforeN(document.getElementById("username").value)' type ="button">Submit</button>
    
    <div id ="amodd" style=display:none>
    <div class = title >ITP-03 Calculator A-M ODD</div>
    <table border="1">
    <tr>
    <td><input type="button" value="c" onclick="clr()"/> </td>
    <td colspan="3"><input type="text" id="calc"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><input type="button" value="+" onclick="dis('+')"/> </td>
    <td><input type="button" value="1" onclick="dis('1')"/> </td>
    <td><input type="button" value="3" onclick="dis('3')"/> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><input type="button" value="/" onclick="dis('/')"> </td>
    <td><input type="button" value="5" onclick="dis('5')"/> </td>
    <td><input type="button" value="7" onclick="dis('7')"/> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><input type="button" value="." onclick="dis('.')"/> </td>
    
    <td><input type="button" value="9" onclick="dis('9')"/> </td>
    <td><input type="button" value="=" onclick="solve()"/> </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </div>   
    
    <script>
        //function for displaying values
        function dis(val)
        {
        document.getElementById("calc").value+=val;
         }
        //function for evaluation
        function solve()
        {
        let x = document.getElementById("calc").value;
        let y = eval(x);
        document.getElementById("calc").value = y;
        }
        //function for clearing the display
        function clr()
        {
        document.getElementById("calc").value = "";
        }
        function isEven() 
        {
        var value = document.getElementById("username").value.length;
        if (value%2 == 0) {
            document.getElementById("check2").innerHTML = "even";
            return true;
        }
        if (value%2 !=0) {
            document.getElementById("check2").innerHTML = "odd";
            return false;
        }
        }
        function beforeN(value) {
        var firstletter = document.getElementById("username").value.substring(0,1);
        var str = "abcdefghijklm.";
        if (str.includes(firstletter)){
            document.getElementById("check1").innerHTML = "a-m";
            return true;
    
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById("check1").innerHTML = "n-z";
            return false;
        }
        }
        if(beforeN(document.getElementById("username").value) && (isEven(document.getElementById("username").value))){
           document.getElementById("amodd").style.display= "block";
        }
        </script>
    </body>
```

and in this line

```
<button onclick='beforeN(document.getElementById("username").value)' type ="button">Submit</button>
```

you missed '